# Server responds with status 200 but Response is empty and only loads after 10 sec

Tags: javascript, rest, vuejs3

I send a request for data to the server, it responds with a status of 200, but the data is loaded only after some time. I checked the request itself without the front part of the application, it only takes about 1 second. It turns out that my application processes the response of this request for a very long time, please tell me how to fix this. The app is written in Vue3.

```
    async getDistributions() {
        try {
          const response = await axios.post(`/api/v1/Workflows/${this.userId}/Distributions`);
          return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
          if (error.response?.data?.message === 'Access Denied.') {
            useToastStore().displayError('accessDenied');
          }
          useToastStore().displayError('DISTRIBUTIONS.SERVICE.ERROR.GET_DISTRIBUTIONS');
        }

  }
```

My code looks like this

I have tried using fast-json-parse, but it did not help. Paginating request is not an option because other developers dont want to change API.

Comment: the delay seems to be on the server side, so ... browser code won't help track down your error